# How to use map in React to create independent children elements

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, setstate, array-map

I can successfully use map to create multiple elements from inside my array, but the button that I'm creating and the state I'm assigning to each child element seems to be tied back to the first mapping. Code here along with screen shot.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './Switch.css'

const Switch = () => {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(true);  
    
    const meats = [
        "Chicken", 
        "Ground Beef",
        "Sausage"
    ]

    const meatSwitches = meats.map((meat) =>
    
            <>
            <div id="ingredientContainer" className={status === true ? 'containerYes' : 'containerNo'}>
                
                    <h2 id='ingredientLabel'>{meat}</h2>
                    <div id="underLabel">
                        <h3 id='yes'>Sounds Yummy! </h3>
                        <input
                            className="react-switch-checkbox"
                            id={`react-switch-new`}
                            type="checkbox"
                            onClick={() => setStatus(!status)}
                            
                        />
                        <label
                            className="react-switch-label"
                            htmlFor={`react-switch-new`}
                        >
                            <span className={`react-switch-button`} />
                        </label>
                        <h3 id='no'>No, thanks.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
    );
```

How can I get each child element to have a functioning button, individual of the first and with independent states (in this case of 'true' and 'false').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 common approaches:

**1. Create a `Meat` child component with its own single `boolean` state**
and keep this state at the child level, independent of the parent component `Switch`. You can pass the `status` data back to parent if you want, via a callback function `onStatusChange`, for example with an `useEffect()`.

```
  const Meat = ({ meat, onStatusChange } ) => {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(true);
    
    useEffect(() => onStatusChange(status), [status])
    
    return (
    <div
      id="ingredientContainer"
      className={status === true ? 'containerYes' : 'containerNo'}
    >
      // ... your jsx code here
    </div>
  }
```

And your `Switch` component will look like this:

```
const Switch = () => {
    const meats = [
        "Chicken", 
        "Ground Beef",
        "Sausage"
    ]

    const [statusList, setStatusList] = useState([]);  
    const handleStatusChange = (status) => {
      // do what you want with the individual status,
      // perhaps push it in a status array?
      setStatusList((prev) => [...prev, status]);
    };

    const meatSwitches = meats.map((meat) => 
      <Meat key={meat} meat={meat} onStatusChange={handleStatusChange} />
    )
```

**2. Use an array of meat types instead of a boolean state to store checkbox values**, then convert it to boolean values later when needed. With this approach you don't have to create a new `Meat` child component.

```
const Switch = () => {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState([]);  
    
    const meats = [
        "Chicken", 
        "Ground Beef",
        "Sausage"
    ];
    
    const handleStatusChange = (event, meat) => {
      if (event.target.checked) {
        // push meat type to list
        // when box is checked
        setStatus(prev => [...prev, meat]);
      } else {
        // remove meat type from list
        // when box is unchecked
        setStatus(prev => return prev.filter(type => type !== meat));
      }
    };

    const meatSwitches = meats.map((meat) =>
      <div
        {/* id and key need to be unique */}
        id={`ingredientContainer-${meat}`}
        key={meat}
        {/* check if box is checked */}
        className={status.includes(meat) ? 'containerYes' : 'containerNo'}
      >
        // code
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onClick={(event) => handleStatusChange(event, meat)}
        />
        // ...
      </div>
    )
```

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: I believe I understand and prefer the second method. In handleStatusChange I'm getting an error on the two inner semi-colons saying that a ',' is expected, but I don't think that's the issue as it's not fixing it. I may just not know React syntax well enough to see where the error is being created. But I understand your solution as definitely getting me close. I just want it to compile now!

Comment: @anon9451 there was a missing closing parentheses `)` at `handleStatusChange`, I fixed it, thank you for pointing out!

Comment: so that did fix that error and I'm seemingly halfway there. Now their statuses are obviously independent as when I click the button for the "Chicken" element, only the color of the chicken element changes which is what I wanted. But the click handlers for all child elements still seem connected to the first. The CSS that I have for the buttons to appear as if they're moving only ever make the first one move and the color of the chicken elements changes even if I click the buttons for OTHER child elements.

Comment: This is one of my first questions by the way and MAN are you a big help!

Comment: @anon9451 I didn't notice until now that you use a single id `id="ingredientContainer"` for ALL the child elements and surely it won't work because each child element is supposed to have a unique `id` and `key`. Since all the child elements have the same `id`, only the first encounter i.e the first child element will be updated when state changes. I updated my code to make sure `id` and `key` for child element are unique, you can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The code is expanded upon slightly and 'answered' below. Thank you @kvooak for your help. Turns out that the checkbox that was hidden in CSS in favor of an unresponsive button (literally just some CSS and no 'input' functionality) was what I needed. I made that checkbox visible, added in a function to add or remove items based on checked status to and from an array, and printed that array at the end in realtime to prove that the app was holding/dumping the right items from array allIngredients.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './Switch.css'


const Switch = () => {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState([]); 
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]); 
    
    let meats = [
        "Chicken", 
        "Ground Beef",
        "Sausage",
        "Pork Chops"
    ];

    let starches = [
        "White Rice", "Bread", "Pasta",
        "Chips", "Idaho Potatoes", "Sweet Potatoes",
        "Tortillas", "Brown Rice", "Red Potatoes"
    ];

    const vegatables = [
        "Broccoli", "Green Beans", "Squash",
        "Corn", "Okra", "Carrots",
        "Onions", "Okra", "Zucchini"
    ]

    const spices = [
        "Cayenne Pepper", "Cumin", "Garlic Powder", 
        "Onion Powder", "Tumeric", "Garam Masala",
        "Chili Powder", "Crushed Red Pepper", "Oregano"
    ]

    let allIngredients = [...checked];

    const handleStatusChange = (event, ingredient) => {
        if (event.target.checked) {
          setStatus(prev => [...prev, ingredient]);
          allIngredients = [...checked, event.target.value];
        } else {
          setStatus(prev => prev.filter(type => type !== ingredient));
          allIngredients.splice(checked.indexOf(event.target.value), 1);
        }
        setChecked(allIngredients);
      };

      var checkedItems = checked.length
        ? checked.reduce((total, item) => {
            return total + ", " + item;
        })
        : "";

    const meatSwitches = meats.map((meat) =>
    
            <>
            <div id="ingredientContainer"  className={status.includes(meat) ? 'containerYes' : 'containerNo'}>
                
                    <p key={meat} id='ingredientLabel'>{meat}</p>
                    
                    <div id="underLabel">
                        <input
                            className="react-switch-checkbox"
                            value = {meat}
                            id={`react-switch-new`}
                            type="checkbox"
                            onClick={(event) => handleStatusChange(event, meat)}
                            
                        />
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
    );

    const starchSwitches = starches.map((starch) =>
    
    <>
    <div id="ingredientContainer"  className={status.includes(starch) ? 'containerYes' : 'containerNo'}>
        
            <p key={starch} id='ingredientLabel'>{starch}</p>
            
            <div id="underLabel">
                <input
                    className="react-switch-checkbox"
                    value={starch}
                    id={`react-switch-new`}
                    type="checkbox"
                    onClick={(event) => handleStatusChange(event, starch)}
                    
                />
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
);

const vegatableSwitches = vegatables.map((vegatable) =>
    
<>
<div id="ingredientContainer"  className={status.includes(vegatable) ? 'containerYes' : 'containerNo'}>
    
        <p key={vegatable} id='ingredientLabel'>{vegatable}</p>
        
        <div id="underLabel">
            <input
                className="react-switch-checkbox"
                value={vegatable}
                id={`react-switch-new`}
                type="checkbox"
                onClick={(event) => handleStatusChange(event, vegatable)}
                
            />
            
        </div>
    </div>
</>
);

const spiceSwitches = spices.map((spice) =>
    
<>
<div id="ingredientContainer"  className={status.includes(spice) ? 'containerYes' : 'containerNo'}>
    
        <p key={spice} id='ingredientLabel'>{spice}</p>
        
        <div id="underLabel">
            <input
                className="react-switch-checkbox"
                value={spice}
                id={`react-switch-new`}
                type="checkbox"
                onClick={(event) => handleStatusChange(event, spice)}
                
            />
            
        </div>
    </div>
</>
);

    return (
    <>
        {meatSwitches}
        {starchSwitches}
        {vegatableSwitches}
        {spiceSwitches}
        {checkedItems}
    </>
  );
};

export default Switch;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the state to be an array of booleans, and have each button correspond to the index. Example:

```
const status, setStatus = useState([true, true, true])
const handleChange = (index) => {
  const prev = [...status];
  prev[index] = !prev[index];
  setStatus(prev);
  
}
const meatSwitches = meats.map((meat,index) =>

        <>
        <div id="ingredientContainer" className={status === true ? 'containerYes' : 'containerNo'}>
            
                <h2 id='ingredientLabel'>{meat}</h2>
                <div id="underLabel">
                    <h3 id='yes'>Sounds Yummy! </h3>
                    <input
                        className="react-switch-checkbox"
                        id={`react-switch-new`}
                        type="checkbox"
                        onClick={() => handleChange(index)}
                        
                    />
                    <label
                        className="react-switch-label"
                        htmlFor={`react-switch-new`}
                    >
                        <span className={`react-switch-button`} />
                    </label>
                    <h3 id='no'>No, thanks.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
);
```